# Can't fetch strings started with a customized keyword

Tags: string, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the strings which started with the keyword `War` or `LPGA` in an wikipedia page. I did not use directly those two keywords; rather, I used them through `keyword` variable because there might be more items to include in that `qsp`.

However, when I run my script using `Like` operator, I get nothing. No error either. I get results when I run the same using `If InStr(post.innerText, keyword) > 0 Then` this block of code. The problem is when I run my script using `InStr()` function, It will fetch me those strings which contain the `keyword` I'm using as variables not the strings which started with that `keyword`.

So, how can I use `Like` operator in my below script to achieve the same.

This is my try so far:

```
Sub FetchInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, qsp As Variant, keyword As Variant, R&

    qsp = [{"War in Donbass","LPGA Tour"}]

    For Each keyword In qsp
        keyword = Split(keyword, " ")(0)
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If post.innerText Like "*keyword" Then
                R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.innerText
            End If
        Next post
    Next keyword
End Sub
```

When I use `InStr()` function then that portion looks like:

```
If InStr(post.innerText, keyword) > 0 Then
    R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.innerText
End If
```

To be clearer: If I wish to search for `War` then I would like to get results like (below results are hypothetical, they might not exist in that site):

```
war house
war of the worlds
```

Not like:

```
city of war
causes of the war
```

Comment: So you want results where the beginning of the string matches the search term? Currently your code obviously isn't working at ll if you're trying to match `"*keyword"`

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: perhaps try: `If post.innerText Like keyword & "*" Then`

Comment: No goddamn way!!!!!! You did it. You made my day @ashleedawg. Please include it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: By the way, a little info on why it should be `"*"` and not  `"* "` or `" *"` would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you like answers very specific to your problem statement....but I was interested in if I could do this with Selenium. So, I ran the following using "War" to see if I could match strings for `a` tags starting with "War". Obviously, this could be extended as per your original example, but does it match the general task?

Side note: I am guessing you could have used `Split` on the `.innerText` and tested the LBound in your example.

---

**XPath**

I use `XPath` and `starts-with` to retrieve the strings.

The XPath query was used on page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_correspondent

---

**Code output:**

[image: Output]

---

It doesn't match items which end with war (Selenium basic doesn't seem to allow for `//a[ends-with(.,'War')]`, but if you use an XPath tester then those retrieved items would be (small sample of results):

[image: Sample results not matched]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, Html As HTMLDocument
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_correspondent"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        Set Html = New HTMLDocument
        Html.body.innerHTML = .FindElementByXPath("//body").Attribute("innerHTML")
        Dim matchedStrings As Object, currentMatch As Long
        Set matchedStrings = .FindElementsByXPath("//a[starts-with(.,'War')]")
        If matchedStrings Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "No matches found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For currentMatch = 1 To matchedStrings.Count
            Debug.Print matchedStrings(currentMatch).Text
        Next currentMatch
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You never fail to amaze. It worked just perfect. I created this post to learn how like operator works.  ashleedawg helped me learn that and you came up with a different approach to satisfy the same which is also very helpful.

Comment: Pleasure. I was worried as I know you have a specific goal always in mind but your questions are interesting and make me think about other things I could try. Now I know how to do this with selenium :-)